# Add together MySQL values forum column

Tags: php, mysql, math, addition

I want to know how I can add (using PHP Math) all the values returned from a MySQL Query.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM phpvms_pireps WHERE pilotid='$pilotcode'")or die(mysql_error());
```

Then for every result it returns, I want it to add together all the values in the distance column together; these are already in number format.

After it's added them together in PHP, echo out the total number.

Thanks.

Comment: why not just use `select sum(phpvms_pireps) as total` ?

Comment: Wow, haven't seen PHPVMS in a while. You starting a VA, OP? Do you happen to be on FSW?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$total = 0;
while ($output = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  $total += $output['distance'];
}

echo $total;
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it in MySQL:

```
SELECT SUM(distance) FROM phpvms_pireps
```

Of course that will not work if you want to select the other values as well.  In that case, you can just do it in the fetch loop:

```
$distance = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) {
    $distance += $row['distance'];
    /* more processing? */
}
echo $distance;
```

---

Your code is query to injection and you are using the deprecated mysql extension.  Switch to properly parameterized queries with PDO or mysqli.

Comment: I think Using `$distances[] = $row['distance'];` and then `$distance = array_sum($distances)` is better.

Comment: @Akam you think that array assignment in a loop plus an additional function call is "better" than simple addition?  How so?